# Reject Delete Statement in trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database where the customer wants run an `DELETE` statement. But on database side, the record should be just hidden instead of deleted.

Can i use a `BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER` to change the `visiblity` flag to `false` instead of deleting the record?

Comment: You mean you want to trick the customer in believing that they deleted some records while in fact those records are only hidden by a flag?

Comment: Yes that's right. So then they call and tell that they accidentally delete something it can quickly be restored. Bye the way the customer off course no about it.

Comment: And the customer is using an interface which allows direct mysql manipulation, like mysql command line client or phpMyAdmin? Or is it a custom interface?

Comment: You can go for Instead of Trigger.

Comment: INSTEAD OF Trigger is only Microsoft SQL(MSSQL). That's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to do this in MySQL (as Alex Monthy hinted, is that really where this logic belongs?) is to use an *after* delete trigger that re-inserts the record with the `visibility` flag set to false:

```
CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER DELETE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO my_table (visibility,     colA,     colB,     colC)
                VALUES (     false, OLD.colA, OLD.colB, OLD.colC);
```

You *can* abort the delete operation from a before trigger (just make the trigger raise an error, e.g. call an non-existent procedure), but that won't enable you to update the `visibility` flag as desired.